# Why and how does this work?

Tags: c, pointers

```
 #define address (*((unsigned int *)10))

 void main()
 {
     unsigned int *p;
     p = &(address);
 }
```

'p' has the value 10. 
How is the above expression evaluated?
Isn't it from inner most brace towards the outermost one? 
But if it is so then '&' has an lvalue which doesn't make sense.
I know that it gets converted to &*(10) which evaluates to 10.

Comment: assign `10` as address to `p`.

Comment: You expect the compiler to know what is at memory location 10? But no, it "boils down" to `p = &*10` = 10. `&0` isn't even meaningful because 0 isn't an lvalue. And what the heck do you mean by "working"? The program doesn't do anything ... or it does everything, since it has undefined behavior.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; `int main(void)` is correct. Whatever book or tutorial told you to use `void main()` was written by someone who doesn't know the language very well.

Comment: @KeithThompson: wasn't concentrating on that part. I know, will edit it.

Comment: @KeithThompson, from the looks of this question, it is probably in the context of an embedded application. Being embedded, it's compiled as a freestanding application as opposed to hosted. In freestanding environments, the name and type of the entry function is implementation defined (C11, 5.1.2.1). So `void main()` could be correct (well actually `void main(void)`). Mind you, this kind of code is quite common in embedded applications were specific addresses are mapped to specific peripherals.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Possibly -- but short snippets like this appear more often in introductory material. There are plenty of bad C books and tutorials out there that recommend `void main()` for hosted implementations.

Comment: Please use a question title that summarizes what you want to know. Putting it in one phrase would already help you to better understand the problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void main()` should be `int main(void)`. Whatever book or tutorial told you to use `void main()` was written by someone who doesn't know the C language very well.

After macro expansion, the body of `main` is equivalent to:

```
unsigned int *p = &(*((unsigned int *)10));
```

If the operand of the unary `&` operator is the result of a unary `*` operator, both operators are omitted (this is stated explicitly in the standard), so the above is equivalent to:

```
unsigned int *p = (unsigned int *)10;
```

This takes the `int` value `10` and converts it from `int` to `unsigned int*`.

The result of an integer-to-pointer conversion is implementation-defined, but is "intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment".

So *if* the idea of "memory address 10" makes sense, then the above will *probably* set `p` to that address.

It's likely that the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned. On many systems, `unsigned int` is 4 bytes and requires 4-byte alignment; 10 is not a multiple of 4.

The code appears to be deliberately obfuscated. The simplified version is more straightforward and not likely to be useful.

In the unlikely event that you know there's an `unsigned int` object at address 10 on your system, and you need to access it, then

```
unsigned int *p = (unsigned int *)10;
```

would be the way to do it.

Comment: Why should that be unlikely? Especially on many smaller µCs it is very likely that there is a register sitting "out there"...

Comment: @glglgl: Most novice C programmers (e.g., anyone who would need to ask this kind of question) aren't likely to be working with small microcontrollers. (And thanks for the edit.)

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't it boil down to `p = &(0)` during the compilation?

No, not at all: the compiler doesn't know that there is the value 0 at the address 10.

It is highly non-portable and is probably supposed to provide a handy identifier - `address` - which can be used to read a value out of a defined place in memory. I suppose it comes from embedded programming.

`address` can be interpreted as an `unsigned int` variable sitting at address 10 and is thus misspelled, because its address - 10 - can only be requested by `&address`.

Answer (score 2):

Oftentimes it is easiest to take this a step at a time when you are working through something you don't understand.  You are on the right track with your question:

> > Isn't it from inner most brace towards the outermost one?

So let's start there.  If you take what is in the innermost braces of your macro, `((unsigned int *)10)`, what does it do?  This statement typecasts the literal value `10`, to be a pointer to an unsigned int.  We now have a pointer to the address 10.  As @glglgl stated, your macro is improperly named.  If you wanted the macro to be an address, this is where you would have ended.  This is a technique that is often used in embedded programming so that you know exactly **what** an address is used for (a particular peripheral register for example).

The next set of braces, `(*((unsigned int *)10))` de-references the pointer that we just typecast.  So the macro is actually giving us the value that is currently being stored at address `10`.

Finally, when you are assigning the value to a pointer `p = &(address);`, you are simply getting the address of value stored at address `10`, which is 10.  You could have just as easily stated `p = (unsigned int *)10;` and had the same result.

Comment: You guessed it right, and it is indeed used to get a register's address. It is from an embedded code. But what surprises me is how the compiler knows that it has to get the address of **that** value itself not any other similar(garbage) value. In this case some random garbage value at address 10. Meaning, say I have two same garbage value at addresses 10 and 20. But how does the compiler go to the correct address '10' but not '20'

Comment: @UchiaItachi, This is because you explicitly tell it to look at address 10 - never 20.  That happens because of the typecast `((unsigned int *)10)`.  It will always look at address 10.

Answer (score 0):

address is a pointer to a memory address (memory address 10), second level indirection. So &adress is the memory address 10, so p is memory address 10.